# 500 OOPS: cannot change directory: /home/user/public_html, VSFTPD error

Tags: server, permissions, directory, vsftpd

I setup VSFTPD on my Ubuntu server 12.04, it worked very good. Until I tried to change the permissions of the user so the user couldn't go in the / directory and only in the directories inside `/home/user/public_html`.

It could have to do something with the fact that I did this:

```
sudo chmod 700 -R /
```

I have a user, ftpUser and he is inside a group, ftpUsers. The permissions of `/home/user/public_html` are:

```
drwxrwxr-x 9 ftpUser ftpUsers 4096
```

My VSFTPD file looks like this:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
connect_from_port_20=NO
chroot_local_user=YES
pam_service=vsftpd
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
```

And in `/etc/vsftpd.userlist` there is only one line: ftpUser

How do I solve this so I can login, it think it has to do something with permissions but I don't now what it is!?

Comment: Is user `ftpUser` a local or a virtual user? And does he has a home dir?

Comment: It's a local user, and the home dir is /home/user/public_html, but now I tried to reboot Ubuntu server and I cannot log in with any account...

Comment: And when you set `chroot_local_user=NO`? Just for checking it that is the problem. I think that it has to do with that.

Comment: Then I still get the same error!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check [this link](http://blog.arithm.com/2009/06/15/defeating-vsftp-error-500-oops-cannot-change-directorysomedirectory/). It worked for me.

> Make sure that the user and group permissions for the account and the home directory match. For example, if you are logging in as:
>
> account:x:521:500::/some/directory:/sbin/nologin
>
> then make sure that the home directory defined for “account” is at
>   least readable and executable by user 521 and group 500.

Comment: As an addition to that post (which says make sure that your directory permissions are OK-- at least readable by the user/group), you also need to ensure that permissions suffice for the parent directories (at least execute permissions).

Answer (score 2):

That error is generated because of Selinux. Please do the following actions:

```
[root@sun02 vsftpd]# getenforce
    Enforcing

[root@sun02 vsftpd]# getsebool -a | grep ftp
    allow_ftpd_anon_write –> off
    allow_ftpd_full_access –> off
    allow_ftpd_use_cifs –> off
    allow_ftpd_use_nfs –> off
    allow_tftp_anon_write –> off
    ftp_home_dir –> off     # We need to change this to on - see next command.
    ftpd_disable_trans –> off
    ftpd_is_daemon –> on
    httpd_enable_ftp_server –> off
    tftpd_disable_trans –> off

[root@sun02 vsftpd]# setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
```

This is all that u want to need.

Good Luck!

source: [Copied and pasted from the above link. Credits to @Jaime M. of http://blog.arithm.com/](http://blog.arithm.com/2009/06/15/defeating-vsftp-error-500-oops-cannot-change-directorysomedirectory/)

Comment: There is a typo in command, it's   "setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on"  not "setseboll -P ftp_home_dir on"